# Storing Data in Session State for a Shopping Cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-first, shopping-cart

trying to take what I have stored adding something to a cart into a session
then transferring it to another page to get a GridView to show up of all the items that I have added onto the Cart session. Storing it as an Object Session.
-AddToCart takes that rows details and stores in A Session then takes that session object and displays it on a Grid view on another page.

takes this code from it:

```
 protected void GridViewDisplay_RowCommand(object sender,
 GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
 if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
 {
 object[] values;
        DataTable orderTable;
        // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
        // CommandArgument property.
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
        // from the Rows collection.
        GridViewRow row = GridViewDisplay.Rows[index];
        values = new Object[GridViewDisplay.Rows[0].Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < GridViewDisplay.Rows[0].Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            values[i] = GridViewDisplay.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text;
        }

       orderTable = (DataTable)Session["OrderLine"];
       orderTable.Rows.Add(values);
       Session["OrderLine"] = orderTable;


    }

}
```

Then Now I am trying to take that and store it in a Session so I can display it on a grid view on another page.

Comment: And what problem are you having? What doesn't work?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: BTW did you look at any of the questions in the "Related" section on the right side of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the issue in the code.

```
protected void GridViewDisplay_RowCommand(object sender,
 GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
 if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
 {
 object[] values;
        DataTable orderTable;
        // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
        // CommandArgument property.
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
        // from the Rows collection.
        GridViewRow row = GridViewDisplay.Rows[index];
        values = new Object[GridViewDisplay.Rows[0].Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < GridViewDisplay.Rows[0].Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            values[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
        }

       orderTable = (DataTable)Session["OrderLine"];
       orderTable.Rows.Add(values);
       Session["OrderLine"] = orderTable;


    }

}
```